# Can't set a test license token in an Outlook addin

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to set a test license token in an Outlook add-in. According to the documentation, I have to set it in the `SourceLocation` in the manifest file:

```
<Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
  <DesktopSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000?et=%3Cr%3E%0A%20%20%3..."/>
    <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
  </DesktopSettings>
</Form>
```

The problem is, when I try to get the URL query params, it won't work. `window.location` looks like this:

`https://localhost:3000/?et=`

Any idea why it's happening?

When I update the source location of the Action `ShowTaskpane`, it won't start the addin:

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <SourceLocation resid="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" />
</Action>

...

<bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000?et=%3Cr%3E%0A%20%20%...">
```

If I set it like this, when I start the addin, it says:

`Sorry, but we can't start this add-in because it isn't set up properly.`

I use the following test token:

```
<r>
  <t 
    aid="WA907006056" 
    pid="{4FB601F2-5469-4542-B9FC-B96345DC8B39}" 
    cid="32F3E7FC559F4F49" 
    did="{0672BAE9-B41B-48FE-87F1-7F4D3DD3F3B1}" 
    ts="30" 
    et="Trial" 
    ad="2012-01-12T21:58:13Z" 
    ed="2019-06-30T21:58:13Z" 
    sd="2012-01-12T00:00:00Z"
    test="true" 
    te="2019-06-30T02:49:34Z" />
  <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

And use the following service to encode the url:

https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: I notice you are adding ?et= to the base section of the manifest. Have you also added the ?et= parameter to all the source locations in the manifest?  Also note that the test license token is relevant for paid addins submitted to office store, so you do not need it if you do not intend to submit a paid addin.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I just updated the source location of action `ShowTaskpane` and it won't let me start the add-in. I updated the question with this new information.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Any updates?

Comment: I have a hunch that it's the format of my test token. I posted it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with URL encoding. When encoding the token, you have to remove all the new lines. Otherwise, it will throw an error. So, before encoding, take the token...

```
<r>
  <t 
    aid="WA907006056" 
    pid="{4FB601F2-5469-4542-B9FC-B96345DC8B39}" 
    cid="32F3E7FC559F4F49" 
    did="{0672BAE9-B41B-48FE-87F1-7F4D3DD3F3B1}" 
    ts="30" 
    et="Trial" 
    ad="2012-01-12T21:58:13Z" 
    ed="2019-06-30T21:58:13Z" 
    sd="2012-01-12T00:00:00Z"
    test="true" 
    te="2019-06-30T02:49:34Z" />
  <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

and remove all the new lines like this:

```
<r> <t aid="WA907006056" pid="{4FB601F2-5469-4542-B9FC-B96345DC8B39}" cid="32F3E7FC559F4F49" did="{0672BAE9-B41B-48FE-87F1-7F4D3DD3F3B1}" ts="30" et="Trial" ad="2012-01-12T21:58:13Z" ed="2019-06-30T21:58:13Z" sd="2012-01-12T00:00:00Z" test="true" te="2019-06-30T02:49:34Z" /> <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d> </r>
```

Finally encode it and add to all the source locations.